# Issue switching controller in code with ros

Tags: c++, linux, controls, ros

I am trying to switch the controller in code but it keeps returning false and i don't know why, this is the code:

```
 ros::ServiceClient switch_controller = n.serviceClient<controller_manager_msgs::SwitchController>("egm/controller_manager/switch_controller");

std::vector<std::string> start_controller;
      start_controller.push_back("joint_group_velocity_controller");
      std::vector<std::string> stop_controller;
      stop_controller.push_back("");
      switch_controller_req.start_controllers = start_controller;
      switch_controller_req.stop_controllers = stop_controller;
      switch_controller_req.strictness = 1;
      switch_controller_req.start_asap = false;
      switch_controller_req.timeout = 0.0;
      ros::service::waitForService("egm/controller_manager/switch_controller", ros::Duration(5));
      success = stop_rapid.call(switch_controller_req,switch_controller_resp);
      if (success)
      {
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Controller switch correctly");

      }
      else
      {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Error occured trying to switch controller");
        return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. The code in the question is C++ and not C, and tagging C wastes the time of people interested in C but not C++.

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification to your code works. Try this out:

```
 ros::ServiceClient switch_controller = n.serviceClient<controller_manager_msgs::SwitchController>("egm/controller_manager/switch_controller");

std::vector<std::string> start_controller;
      start_controller.push_back("joint_group_velocity_controller");
      std::vector<std::string> stop_controller;
      stop_controller.push_back("");
      controller_manager_msgs::SwitchController switch_controller_req;
      switch_controller_req.request.start_controllers = start_controller;
      switch_controller_req.request.stop_controllers = stop_controller;
      switch_controller_req.request.strictness = 1;
      switch_controller_req.request.start_asap = false;
      ros::service::waitForService("egm/controller_manager               /switch_controller", ros::Duration(5));
        switch_controller.call(switch_controller_req);
      if (switch_controller_req.response.ok)
      {
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Controller switch correctly");

      }
      else
      {
        ROS_ERROR_STREAM("Error occured trying to switch controller");
        return 0;
      }
```